# Procedure to interface an I2C device on Upsquared board

Tags: debugging, i2c, gpio, upsquared

I have connected the SDA and SCL pins of the mux with pins 3 and 5 respectively. Furthermore, I tried to read the data using the sample i2c test program AAEON provided.

I am unable to read or write date to my i2c details.

[image]

what am I missing?

Comment: Is `0x70` 8-bit or 7-bit address? If the former, try `0x38` instead.